# How to highlight all column with 2 colors only by continuous duplicated group of cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I want to highlight the rows based on the cells value of a column like below, please advise:

```
aa --> yellow
aa --> yellow
bb --> green
bb --> green
cc --> yellow
cc --> yellow
dd --> green
dd --> green
ee --> yellow
ee --> yellow
ee --> yellow
kk --> green
kk --> green
kk --> green
kk --> green
kk --> green
```

... so on the  duplicated groups

Comment: are aa, bb, cc, dd an actual values?

Comment: hi player0, no actual it can be any different values, and the rows  of continuous duplicated cells can be more than 2, or just 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your entries are in ColumnA please select range to suit and

1. highlight ('standard') all in green then
2. Format > Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... Custom formula is and:

   ```
   =isodd(match(A1,UNIQUE(A:A),0))
   ```

with yellow highlighting.

To extend the width either start with selecting all "whole rows" instead of ColumnA, or adjust the Applies to range to suit, and then replace all capital `A`s above (3 off) with `$A`s.

Answer (score 0):

**yellow:** `=REGEXMATCH(A1, "aa|cc")`

**green:** `=REGEXMATCH(A1, "bb|dd")`

[image]

---

**yellow:** `=REGEXMATCH($A1, "aa|cc")`

**green:** `=REGEXMATCH($A1, "bb|dd")`

[image: 0]

---

**yellow:** `=IF((MOD(ROW(A1),4)=1)+(MOD(ROW(A1),4)=2),1)`

**green:** `=IF((MOD(ROW(A1),4)=3)+(MOD(ROW(A1),4)=0),1)`

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi player, what if it continue like: ( the duplicated group of cell quantity can be 2 cells or 3 cells or.. more )


ee
ee
ee
ff
ff
oo
oo
oo

Comment: in that case you will need to use regexmatch formulas and state variables

Comment: I am new with the sheets, can you please advise?

Comment: @KevinNgo first or second set of formulas from this answer